# I m trying to make pipelined table function call but i m getting error in package body. Can u please make it correct

Tags: plsql

```sql
create or replace Type e_record AS Object(
        e_uid number,
        e_first_name varchar2(50) ,
        e_last_name varchar2(50),
        e_age number,
        e_department varchar2(50),
        e_designation varchar2(50),
        e_salary number
);

create or replace Type e_record_table IS table Of e_record; 



Create or replace package E_package
AS 
    
    function list_empDetails return e_record_table pipelined;

end E_package;
/

-------Package Body----------


Create or replace package body E_package 
AS

    Function list_empDetails return e_record_table pipelined
    IS
        e_ret e_record_table := e_record_table(null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    Begin
        for x in(select e_uid,e_first_name,e_last_name,e_age,e_department,e_designation,e_salary into e_ret from Employee_details) Loop
        pipe row(e_ret);
        End Loop;
        return;
    end list_empDetails;
end E_package;
/
```

And the error i m getting is :

```
Error at line 8: PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
Error at line 9: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error at line 9: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
Error at line 8: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

Firstly, the `not enough values` error was because you are querying 7 columns and only providing one variable to put them in in the `INTO` clause.  However, you don't use the `INTO` clause when looping over the results of a query that way, so the first thing you can do is to get rid of it.  Your loop variable `x` will contain each row of data read from your `Employee_details` table, you don't need another variable for it.

The next thing to note is that you declared `e_ret` of type `e_record_table`.  Your pipelined function returns `e_record_table`, but the type of each row you pipe out needs to be the type your table type contains, not the table type.  The `expression is of wrong type` error is because you were attempting to pipe out a value of type `e_record_table`.  Anyway, you're not selecting anything into `e_ret` any more, so you can just delete this local variable.

Your loop variable `x` contains each row read from the query.  As written, it contains 7 values, so you could create an `e_record` row to pipe back using something like the following:

```sql
        pipe row(e_record(x.e_uid, x.e_first_name, x.e_surname, x.e_age, ...));
```

However, that makes quite a lot of typing since you are repeating the list of columns in your query.  You can avoid the duplicated typing by creating the record in the query and then piping that out:

```sql
        for x in(select e_record(e_uid,e_first_name,e_last_name,e_age,e_department,e_designation,e_salary) as emp from Employee_details) Loop
            pipe row(x.emp);
        End Loop;
```

The full working function is below:

```sql
    Function list_empDetails return e_record_table pipelined
    IS
    Begin
        for x in(select e_record(e_uid,e_first_name,e_last_name,e_age,e_department,e_designation,e_salary) as emp from Employee_details) Loop
            pipe row(x.emp);
        End Loop;
        return;
    end list_empDetails;
```